# Why is my SCR controlled by a photodiode pulsing when supplied with high voltage

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, photodiode, thyristor

I am working on a circuit which when a photogate (consisting of a photodiode and a corresponding LED) is interrupted, an SCR is triggered which discharges a capacitor through a solenoid. I built and tested the circuit in which the capacitor was replaced with a 30V power supply and the coils were replaced with a motor in order to facilitate trouble shooting (as seen below). The working principle is a 5v supply will send current through the photodiode and when the gate is interrupted the current will stop flowing through the photodiode and a not-gate will then send current to an NPN transistor. Said NPN then sends current to the SCR Gate which is in series with the motor and 30v supply. The problem is when I tested it the motor will rapidly pulse on and off, and then when the motor comes to almost a complete stop it will pulse again and this will repeat indefinitely when the gate is broken. I am definitely a nooby at this kind of stuff (aerospace engineer by trade) so any advice is appreciated.
[image: schematic of circuit]

Comment: Can you specify the motor current free running at 30 V and the available current from the 5 V supply? This photo diode symbol is not used for a complete photo-electric guard. If it is really a pure photo diode, it can not be used this way.

Comment: There are many problems with this circuit. I think you should start over by replacing the SCR with a logic level NMOS device which can be driven directly from the inverter, although it would be better to use a 74HC14 Schmitt trigger. There should be a commutating diode across the motor or solenoid. I am assuming you want the motor to stop when the light to the photodiode is restored.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on many assumptions, it is just an attempt.

One would expect, that the thyristor keeps conducting once triggered, because there is a DC load. But the datasheet says, that the holding current is 200 mA. My first assumption is, that during the spin up of the motor the current will be above the holding current but drops below it once a stable rotation speed is reached. At this time the thyristor stops conducting and the motor speed will come down again.

My second assumption is, that the 5 V supply will collapse if the transistor turns on, because there is no current limiting resistor in the gate path. The 74HC04 may deliver 5 mA which could allow around 500 mA peak transistor current.

So I suggest this scenario: The transistor triggers the thyristor with a dangeous high current peak and starts the motor. The 5 V supply collapses and recovers with a low frequency. Periodically this triggers the thyristor. So new motor spin up cycles are started and stop after a short time in an unpredictable interval.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I replaced the motor with an LED and a resistor and the pulsing stopped. The issue is that when I use the capacitors instead of the 30v supply there will be a huge surge current which I believe will be within the design tolerances of the thyristor but I dont want the NPN to cut off the current discharge. Should I run a resistor from the NPN's emitter to the ground?

Comment: Replace the diode D1 by something between 22 and 47 ohm (too lazy to calculate) to limit the NPN current. Be sure that the recharge current of the coming big capacitor is below the holding current of the thyristor or you have only one shot.